# How to Write a Visual Studio Macro to "Collapse to Definition" without Collapsing Comments?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros, comments, region, code-folding

One of the thing that I would love in Visual Studio is when I collapse to definitions (or use other code-folding options in VS).  I personally/humbly disagree with [using the region directive](http://coderob.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/why-i-hate-the-region-directive/), so I'm looking for an alternative to that.

There isn't anything built-in to VS (as far as I know in VS 2010), so I think the answer would be a macro.  I have zero experience with macros. Can anyone give some idea on what this macro would look like, or ideas on how to write it?  Thanks!